# Why trap ERR failed in sub function of bash?

Tags: bash

I like to use 'set -e' to stop at the first occurrence of an error.
But it is difficult to tell on which line the error occurs when the 'set -x' is not set.

So, I wish I could use `trap ERR` to show the error line.
But, it failed, in the following test script which try to stop at subs1, but only sub2 will stopped by trap.  What's the proper way to show error line number when the exit code is not 0?

My test script as follow

```
#!/bin/bash

subs() {
  echo "before false1: $LINENO"
  false 1
  echo "after false1: $LINENO"
}
subs2() {
  echo "before false2: $LINENO"
  false 2
}
failed() {
  local r=$?
  local line=${last_lineno:-$1}
  echo "Err: return $r at $line: $BASH_COMMAND"
  echo "Trace: " "$@"
  exit $r
}
main() {
  trap 'failed $LINENO ${BASH_LINENO[@]}' ERR
  subs
  subs2
  echo "end:$LINENO"
}
main "$@"
```

The output is (on bash 4.4.12)

```
before false1: 4
after false1: 6
before false2: 9
Err: return 1 at 22: false 2
Trace:  22 25 0
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Where exactly is your offending instruction? `false 1` or `false 2` won't return non zero exit codes

Comment: Can you remove the current example and provide a minimal one? You just want to trap the ERR signal and identify which line is causing the error?

Comment: Insert `trap '...' ERR` to first line of every function.

Comment: ... and your assignments using `local`, `local r=$?` is incorrect, always separate variable initialization and variable assignments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place use this directive at the start of your script to make your `ERR` trap inherited by shell function. By default `ERR` trap is not inherited.

```
set -E
```

As per `help set`:

> `-E`  If set, the `ERR` trap is **inherited** by shell functions.

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/krOLEH)

Your complete code:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -E

subs() {
  echo "before false1: $LINENO"
  false 1
  echo "after false1: $LINENO"
}

subs2() {
  echo "before false2: $LINENO"
  false 2
}

failed() {
  local r=$?
  set -- "${@:1:$(($#-1))}"
  # local line=${last_lineno:-$1}
  echo "Err: return $r at $1: $BASH_COMMAND"
  echo "Trace: " "$@"
  exit $r
}

main() {
  trap 'failed $LINENO ${BASH_LINENO[@]}' ERR
  subs
  subs2
  echo "end:$LINENO"
}

main "$@"
```

**Output:**

```
$> bash trapScript.sh

before false1: 5
Err: return 1 at 6: false 1
Trace:  6 26 31
```